# Split keyboard has two different keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I use Windows.

I have the following split keyboard "Mistel BAROCCO MD770 TKL Split Mechanical Keyboard with Cherry MX Blue Switch, Ergonomic Keyboard with Orange Letter PBT Double Shot Keycaps for Windows and Mac, Programmable Macro Support, ANSI/US"

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B082FWR2RW/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082FWR2RW)

For many months, it has worked fine. Recently, the right hand has suddenly switched to the [Dvorak simplified keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_keyboard_layout). I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the driver's and this didn't work.

The left hand meanwhile has a standard US QWERTY layout.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Which operating system - Windows? Which drivers? What do you have in *Settings > Time & Language > Language* under "Preferred languages" (a screenshot will help)?